# Titanium: Uncaught Error: no such table

Tags: database, sqlite, titanium

Database has been installed but can't access

I have *kwf.db3* file in "*/app*" folder

- In */app/controllers/search.js* file:

I have installed *kwf* by script: *var db = Ti.Database.install('../kwf.db3', 'keywords');*

To confirm success, I have read *"keywords" Database* by script:

```
var text;
var openMyFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile("file://data/data/"+ Ti.App.getId()+"/databases/keywords");
    if(openMyFile.exists())
    {text  = openMyFile.read().toString();}
```

*"text"* has retrieved *keywords* content. => Successful Installing.

BUTTTT

When I excute SELECT query,

```
var db = Ti.Database.open('keywords');
var searchKeyWords = db.execute("SELECT SearchText from SearchKeyWords WHERE SearchText LIKE '%bay%' ORDER BY Length(SearchText) ASC  LIMIT 15");
```

I got an error (Uncaught error: no such table)

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50234898/kwf_err.png

I had ran this query in SQLite Manager but I got no error
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50234898/kwf_exc.png

Help me, please!!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

first and for most, you need to close database connection after installation of database.

then to confirm that database is installed or not , you should use ddms.

and for android we generally add /(slash) before path so try to do install it by following line..

```
var db = Ti.Database.install('/../kwf.db3', 'keywords');
db.close();
```